# How should I secure data on other partitions before lending my PC?

Tags: windows, partitioning, security

I am going to travel for a few months so I will give my sister access to my PC. I plan to just do a factory reset on Windows and give her an admin account to prevent complication while I am away. However I do have some work data on another partition (on separated drives). I am not as worried about her accessing it but more about she may get the computer infected with ransomware/malware that could get some sensitive data (due to me working 100% from home with a few sensitive data on my drive).

Although losing data is not a concern since everything *should* have an online copy, I'd rather have them there ready when I return. If possible, I'd rather her being able to use the free space of the partition as well. What is a good way to secure the data before giving the PC access to my sister? Those are a few things I thought up:

- Hide the partitions away, but then my sister cannot use those extra partitions and I think it's just an "amateur" prevention.
- Zip everything as a password protected file and delete original files. Downside I can think of is it takes quite some time before and after. Also I am not sure but I think the file name entries are available without password - I don't want this.
- Protect the drive with BitBlocker. I have never used this before so I assume it simply lock a whole partition down? So it has the same downside as 1st one and I can't unlock it if I reset Windows?

Comment: I suggest physically removing the drive from the computer and adding in a cheap SSD of a suitable size for her to use.

Comment: Backup the data. That’s the only protection against randsomeware

Comment: Best way to secure data is Do Not Lend It!

Answer (score 1):

If you physically remove the drive from the computer and store it somewhere safe then it won't be vulnerable to anything that happens to the computer, such as malware or coffee.

You can install a low-cost SSD for her to use as data storage.

Comment: This is a valid and good answer. However for my case, I prefer not changing the hardware and using software/configuration solution if possible. I know it's a custom build PC but overtime I just see opening the case a great hassle, not to mention I have 2 SSDs and 1 HDD with "improvised" cables that I do not understand